# getSingleResult returns proxy on native scalar query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on switching my JPA persistence provider from EclipseLink 2.3 to Hibernate 3.6.5.Final.  The problem is with a native query.  Note: this wasn't a problem with EclipseLink.  I'm trying to obtain a scalar value, a `String` from a table that I don't have an Entity declared for.  Here is the code:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select description from foo where foo_id = ?");
q.setParameter(1, fooId);
String description = (String)q.getSingleResult();
```

With Hibernate I get a `ClassCastException` because the object returned is actually a proxy object.  I don't know what type it is, but I know it isn't an array (`object.getClass().isArray()` is false) and I know it isn't a List (`object instanceof List` is `false`).

What am I missing?

Comment: What interfaces does `q.getSingleResult().getClass().getInterfaces()` return?

Comment: Ahhh... that was what I needed.  It is of type java.sql.Clob, org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.WrappedClob, and java.io.Serializable.  If you make that an answer I'll accept it.  I didn't even realize the column was a clob and I'm surprised EclipseLink was doing the conversion to String for me.

Comment: Just FYI two other issues came up with the conversion to Hibernate. (1) calling a getEntityXList() method on an EntityY to force the EntityManager to query the database and load the lazy loaded list worked in EclipseLink, but I had to make it getEntityXList().size() for it to work in Hibernate. (2) an untyped criteria query worked in EclipseLink, but in Hibernate I get an exception about no selection.  I just added the type: CriteriaQuery<EntityX> cq = builder.createQuery(EntityX.class);

Comment: Worked for me!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993398/hibernate-createnativequery-returning-proxy-object-for-clob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Summarizing comments below the question:*

> What interfaces does `q.getSingleResult().getClass().getInterfaces()` return?

---

> It is of type `java.sql.Clob`, `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.WrappedClob`, and `java.io.Serializable`. [...] I didn't even realize the column was a clob and I'm surprised EclipseLink was doing the conversion to String for me

---

Looks like EclipseLink is smart enough to convert CLOB (which is actually a very long sequence of characters, just like `String`) to `String` if required. With Hibernate this must be done explicitly. I guess this complies to the JPA specification.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the right database dialect for hibernate? The dialect is used to map the type of scalar values.

Comment: I'm using an Oracle database and I've got it configured in a DataSource in my application server.  When Hibernate initializes it reports in the logs - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect so I guess it figured it out.